# Java logical OR as per user input

Tags: java

Requirement:
The program looks if a string is equal to the one or any of the characters entered by the user. The user may enter any numbers of entries separated by commas.

### In essence the code should be

```
if user inputs one value (X) // in[0] = X;

if(str.equals(in[0]))
{
// do something
}
```

---

```
if user inputs two values (X,Y) // in[0] = X; in[1] = Y;

if(str.equals(in[0]) || str.equals(in[1]))
{
// do something
}
```

---

```
if user inputs three values (X,Y,Z) // in[0] = X; in[1] = Y; in[2] = Z;

if(str.equals(in[0]) || str.equals(in[1]) || str.equals(in[2]))
{
// do something
}
```

And so on......
As you can see I cannot write such a dynamic if statement.
I would have liked to have something like the below work. Any suggestions?

Trial code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class test {

 public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

 System.out.println("Enter the characters separated by commas");
 BufferedReader consoleinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String input = consoleinput.readLine();
 input = input.toUpperCase();
 String[] in = input.split(",");

 String str = "N";
 if (str.equals(in))
 {
 System.out.println("Match found"); 
 }
 else
 {
 System.out.println("No match"); 
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Nope. This is a small simplified part (for discussion sake) of a larger program

Comment: Is that larger program homework?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is some sort of loop.

```
foreach(string str : in) {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way, other than using loops.

I already have it working with loops using regex as well as AbstractScriptEngine

Comment: No. You can't execute a block of code an arbitrary number of times without a loop of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons CLI library](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) provides an API for parsing command line options passed to programs

Answer (score 0):

Do you look for something like this?

```
if (Arrays.asList(in).contains(str)) {
  // do something
}
```